# Problems sorting model data correctly

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm having troubles correctly sorting the data coming from my database.

My setup: I am using Django + Django Rest Framework extensively and VueJS as the frontend. I have a database table that contains messages with a `ForeignKey` reference to a user. These messages come from different contacts (phone numbers) and I want to be able to group them in conversations. This way, on the frontend, I will be able to see one conversation box containing all the messages with that `phone_number`, in another a separate conversation with a different `phone_number` etc.

The way I want it arranged is that I want the most recent conversation box to appear on the top left, second most recent right of it, and then keep going with the least-most-recent in the bottom right.

This is the Django model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    phone_number_clean = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In my Django Rest Framework views file, I overrode the `list()` method like so:

```
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).order_by("date_time") # get the data ordered by date_time
serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
data = serializer.data
data.sort(key=itemgetter("phone_number"))
conversation_list = []

for key, group in itertools.groupby(data, lambda item: item["phone_number"]):
    conversation_dict = {}
    messages = [item for item in group][-50:]  # Get only the last 50 messages per phone_number
    conversation_dict["messages"] = messages  # A list of all the messages
    conversation_dict["conversation_key"] = key
    conversation_list.append(conversation_dict)

return Response(conversation_list)
```

I am using `itertools.groupby()` in order to group my messages by the `phone_number`. For that reason, my understanding is that I have to use `data.sort(key=itemgetter("phone_number"))` because the `groupby()` does not work if the `phone_number` records are scattered all over the place. Unfortunately, it's that `data.sort()` that changes the sorting and I lose my original `order_by("date_time")` sorting completely.

I have tried many things. I have tried calling `data.sort(key=itemgger("date_time")` both before and after the original call. If I call it before, it has no effect; if I call it after, I lose the `phone_number` sort. I tried passing `date_time` as the second argument to the `data.sort()`, it did not work. I tried other things that I can't even remember now - none of them produced any results.

I have been working on this for 1.5 days already and I'm stuck. Would appreciate any ideas including how to better group my data and how to get both the grouping and the `date_time` sorting done correctly.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I really need to start a religion or something. Every time I post a question on SO, I am able to answer it by myself within 30 minutes.

This is what I did:

QuerySet now looks like this:

```
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).order_by("phone_number_clean", "date_time")
```

I added another `conversation_dict` parameter in my `groupby()` loop:

```
conversation_dict["last_date"] = messages[-1]["date_time"]
```

Essentially it just grabs the date of the last message for that conversation.

AFTER the `groupby` loop, I simply do:

```
conversation_list.sort(key=itemgetter("last_date"))
```

And I get the results that I wanted. *Voila!*